# jquery multiple dialoge boxes

Tags: jquery

Hi i am trying to put multiple dialog boxes in a single page. i had downloaded demo for a single dialog box and apply same effect to different "div"s.. but it came on the same position. how can i put diff. dialog boxes in diff positions ? i has set styles for 2nd and 3rd "div"s; but its not working.. somebody please help me..

this is my code..

jQuery UI Dialog - Default functionality

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../ui/jquery.ui.mouse.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../ui/jquery.ui.draggable.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="../../ui/jquery.ui.dialog.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" href="../demos.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog();
});

$(function() {
    $("#two").dialog();
});

</script>
```

regards tismon

Comment: Show code. What jQuery plugin are you using?

Answer (score 1):

> Specifies where the dialog should be
>   displayed. Possible values:
>
> 1. a single string representing
>      position within viewport: 'center',
>      'left', 'right', 'top', 'bottom'.
> 2. an array containing an x,y
>      coordinate pair in pixel offset from
>      left, top corner of viewport (e.g.
>      [350,100])
> 3. an array containing x,y position
>      string values (e.g. ['right','top']
>      for top right corner).

Code examples

Initialize a dialog with the position option specified.

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog( { position: 'top' } );
```

Get or set the position option, after init.

```
//getter
var position = $( ".selector" ).dialog( "option", "position" );

//setter
$( ".selector" ).dialog( "option", "position", 'top' );
```

[source](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#option-position)
quick [demo](http://jsbin.com/usiya3)